# Records Update, but when grabbed from PHP file, do not change

Tags: php, mysql

So let's say my records say 25, 8 and 7 inside the mySQL database. But when I grab the records from the database they show up as 2, 3 and 4.

Is it something to deal with the select? Because that is the only statement I am using to grab these variables:

```
$poll1c1 = (int) mysql_query("SELECT choice1 from poll1");
$poll1c2 = (int) mysql_query("SELECT choice2 from poll1");
$poll1c3 = (int) mysql_query("SELECT choice3 from poll1");
```

If there is anything wrong with this and to cause the records grabbed to NOT be updated. Please let me know.

Thanks, Chris

Comment: `mysql_query` returns  a result `resource`, use `mysql_fetch_result`....

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_query()` doesn't return the record it just returns a result. You have to fetch the record. Also you should fetch with one query. Not three.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT choice1, choice2, choice3 FROM poll1");
if( $result ) {
     list($poll1c1, $poll1c2,$poll1c3) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
}
else {
     echo mysql_error();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error."

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

You really should read the manual first, than start programming.

You can also find some working examples on the manual page.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you use [`mysql_query`](https://www.php.net/mysql_query), you should perhaps review the docs.

```
$r=mysql_query("SELECT choice1,choice2,choice3 from poll1");
if ($r) {
   //Assumes there's only ever one row... which seems quite 
   // unlikely but it's the way you wrote it.
   $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
   $poll1c1 = (int)$row["choice1"];//Cast may be unnec. depending on column type
   $poll1c2 = (int)$row["choice2"];
   $poll1c3 = (int)$row["choice3"];
   mysql_free_result($r);
}
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! What should I review concerning this. I'd like to know. I'm a little confused as to what mysql_fetch_assoc() and mysql_free_result do precisely.

Comment: @ChrisCates `mysql_query` executes the SQL and generates a result (`$r`), `mysql_fetch_assoc` fetches a row of data from the result as a named array, when you're expecting multiple rows of results you need to call this repetitively until it's false (in this case we're only expecting one row) `mysql_free_result` releases the results you generated in `mysql_query` - freeing up memory and resources (it's good housekeeping)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the actual result from your query, you will have to use `mysql_fetch_*` e.g. `mysql_fetch_assoc`. You are just converting the Resource to and int. Also beware that the order in which mysql passed the tuples, is arbitrary unless you specify an `ORDER BY`-clause.

[See the PHP documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)